# Proving that the exterior algebra is symmetric via the polynomial ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Recall that a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $K$ is called Frobenius in case $A \cong D(A)$ as right modules, and it is called symmetric in case $A \cong D(A)$ as bimodules (where $D=Hom_K(-,K)$).

It is known that the Koszul dual algebra $A^{!}$ of an Artin-Schelter regular Koszulalgebra $A$ is a finite dimensional Frobenius algebra.

> Question 1: In case $A=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is the polnyomial ring in $n$ variables over a field $K$ of characteristic 0, $A^{!}$ is an exterior algebra and in case I made no mistake this should be symmetric if and only if $n$ is odd. My question is whether one can prove this just by looking at $K[x_1,...,x_n]$. Or asked differently: What property corresponds to being symmetric in $K[x_1,...,x_n]$, if there is any? (so $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ should have this property only for odd $n$)
>
> Question 2 (more general): Is there a condition on $A$ that describes when $A^{!}$ is a symmetric algebra?